# Pandas DataFrame naming only 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way with Pandas Dataframe to name only the first or first and second column even if there's 4 columns :

Here

```
for x in range(1, len(table2_query) + 1):
    if x == 1:
        cursor.execute(table2_query[x])
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=cursor.fetchall(), columns=['Q', col_name[x-1]])
```

and it gives me this :

> AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] containing a small dataset that produces the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
```

[image]

then use `rename` and pass a dictionary with the name changes to the argument `columns`:

```
df.rename(columns=dict(A='a', B='b'))
```

[image]

#### Instantiating a DataFrame while only naming a subset of the columns

When constructing a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame`, you either don't pass an index/columns argument and let pandas auto-generate the index/columns object, or you pass one in yourself.  If you pass it in yourself, it must match the dimensions of your data.  The trouble of mimicking the auto-generation of pandas while augmenting just the ones you want is not worth the trouble and is ugly and is probably non-performant.  In other words, I can't even think of a good reason to do it.

On the other hand, it is super easy to rename the columns/index values.  In fact, we can rename just a few.  I think below is more in line with the spirit of your question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)).rename(columns=str).rename(columns={'1': 'A', '3': 'F'})
df
```

[image]

Comment: That would be in last resort but considering Your example...
Is there a way to code it like this:
    pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(2,4, columns=(`A`)
I don't mind what the others columns name are....
Thanks

Comment: @MathieuL'Allier Updated post.  I addressed your comment towards the end of the post.

Comment: I agree. Is there a good reason for not using rename afterwards?